Changing the commentstyle color for an existing language in listings?
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
// this is a main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return 0; // return 0 here
}
\end{lstlisting}

That's it, folks!
\end{document}

The listings package already has a C language definition, as it can be seen in the output:

All I want to do beyond that, is to have the comments in C language colored gray.
I am aware that I can do \lstset{commentstyle=\color{black!60}} - but as far as I understand, this will change the commentstyle color globally, which I do not want. (EDIT: Although, I could add the commentstyle within the environent options, which would not change it globally:
% ...
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,commentstyle=\color{gray}]
% ...

... and it still works - although it kills the previously set italic:

)
Anyways - I'd want to only patch in / add \color{black!60} to the existing commentstyle only for the C language, preferably without re-running the entire \lstdefinelanguage{C} as it is in the defaults of the listings package.
Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,commentstyle=\color{gray}\itshape] gray and italic

The easiest is with a style:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{Cgray}{language=C,commentstyle=\color{gray}\itshape}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\begin{lstlisting}[style=Cgray]
// this is a main function in C
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return 0; // return 0 here
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
// this is a main function in C++
int main() {
  return 0; // return 0 here
}
\end{lstlisting}

That's it, folks!
\end{document}

Result:

However, if you want to keep the syntax language=C instead of style=something, then you can hook to the initialization of listings, check if the language is equal to c (note that listings changes C to c internally), and if yes then locally redefine the commentstyle.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\def\checkC{c}
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{\ifx\lst@language\checkC\def\lst@commentstyle{\color{gray}\itshape}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
// this is a main function in C
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  return 0; // return 0 here
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C++]
// this is a main function in C++
int main() {
  return 0; // return 0 here
}
\end{lstlisting}

That's it, folks!
\end{document}

Output is the same.

Indeed, I wanted to keep the syntax language=C - thanks a ton for including that part in the answer as well!
